# Creating an animated checkmard in ExtJS Classic 7.3.0. Need help removing the container border around my check mark

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, extjs

I am trying to display a check mark on top of all my components. Its showing, but there is a frame for the container around my check mark, and I don't know how to remove it. Here is the working fiddle: [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3dqo). Click on the submit button, and you will see how it looks currently.

Also including the code here:

```
    var checkMarkTemplate = new Ext.XTemplate(
      '<svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">',
      '<circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none"/>',
      '<path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8"/>',
    );

    Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
        floating: true,
        // modal: true,
        id: 'check',
        renderTpl: checkMarkTemplate,
        frame: false,
        border: false,
        bodyStyle: 'background:transparent',
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        listeners: {
            show: function(comp) {
                //
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `shadow:false,` in the above `Ext.create('Ext.Component', {`

That got it working for me.